# Undefined variable Login

Tags: php, html, xampp, login

estoy trabajando en un login con posibilidad de conectarse a google y anda bien, de hecho, hice una base de datos para guardar el email y el nombre del usuario. Pero hay un pequeño problema.

Resulta, que este es el Código de vinculación con la base de datos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y al ingresar, los datos se cargan en la base de datos correctamente.
Pero en la parte inicial del login, me aparece el siguiente error (aunque me deja realizar el proceso de logearse y guardar los datos bien):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Nota: autenticacion.php es el archivo donde tengo el código que mostré.

Ahora, si yo cambio $email y $name a solamente email y name, el error desaparece, pero claro, en la base de datos no se guardan los datos, solo esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguno tiene alguna idea de que podría estar mal? Gracias por la atencion.

Comment: Empezamos por el principio... el código es texto, por favor PONLO COMO TAL! Una imagen de código **NO ES ACEPTABLE**. Y en cuanto a tu problema.. estás definiendo $email DENTRO DE UN IF. Cualquier variable definida dentro de un bloque de código (como un if, un try, una función...) solo está disponible DENTRO DE ESE BLOQUE. Declara la variable `$email = ''` ANTES DEL IF, y dentro del if simplemente la asignas.

Comment: Okay @Benito-B, mas tarde lo intentare, muchas gracias por tu aporte

Comment: Efectivamente funciono, muchas gracias @Benito-B!!!

Comment: por favor no agregues imagenes de codigo o errores por favor!